# how to resize a grid in main window from a user control - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a close button in a user control. When click that i want to hide a grid in the main window
I want to control via this button

```
private void PWChangeClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation dAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

        dAnim.From = 0;
        dAnim.To = 120;
        dAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4);
        dAnim.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase();

        MainWindow Main = new MainWindow();
        Main.grdDockTop.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, dAnim);
    }
```

but this is not working
grdDockTop is the grid in Mainwindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access main window properties and fields by getting its instance

```
private void PWChangeClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation dAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

        dAnim.From = 0;
        dAnim.To = 120;
        dAnim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4);
        dAnim.EasingFunction = new QuadraticEase();

        //MainWindow Main = new MainWindow(); Change this to: 
        var Main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

        Main.grdDockTop.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, dAnim);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in code behind without MVVM pattern you need to access the exact instance of the MainWindow.

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public static MainWindow mainWindowInstace;
    MainWindow()
    {
        mainWindowInstace=this;
    }
}
```

And access the Grid like

```
MainWindow.mainWindowInstace.grdDockTop
```